# Can't connect to wifi - device not ready - ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10

Just upgraded to 16.10 and the network menu says device not ready and does not even detect the network. This is despite the fact that during installation the connection worked fine. Ethernet wired connection works fine

Comment: just to add rfkill list says that its not blocked

Comment: Is it a PCI or a USB device?

Comment: It is a PCI device.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself after a boot into windows 10 (I dual boot) without any indication as to why. I had of course rebooted several times from ubuntu before posting the question. I would still be interested in understanding what the issue was. As requested here is the output from lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 com
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]